# Can I somehow play an HEVC movie on a core2 duo computer?

Tags: video, graphics-card, codec, intel-core2

I have a core 2 Duo, E8400, radeon4350 RV710, Optiplex 755, 4GB RAM 332mhz DRam DDR2 DUal channel and I ask if I can play HEVC coded movies with a software trick or something?

Comment: If your hardware isn't up to playing HEVC, you could convert it with ffmpeg, but there are people claiming ffplay can be used if you don't have a core-I7.

Comment: I play HEVC 720p movies on Pentium III. It depends on e.g. operating system (configuration, optimization, drivers etc.), player (try VLC or MPC-HC) and at last but not least - movie. To play 1080p movie you need usually more power than with 480p, but in some cases 480p might need even more resources. Be sure you don't use some postprocessing (which is common with some graphic card drivers - turn off anything in drivers control panel anything that could affect movie play), try to turn off background processes you don't use, get a light player. If you still have problems, try tuning player.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is too weak. You can try using GPU acceleration e.g. for VLC to see if that works: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding/

If that doesn't work (your GPU is very slow as well) you may want to try to convert the file for example with a tool like handbrake. Convert it using a less intensive codec and consider lowering the resolution of the file. It'll take a while and the qualtiy will be worse, but you'll be able to play the video file.